# How to set different style and name for each feature individually OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, style

I am trying to style each feature with different style and set properties like name dynamically  like in
[this](https://geojson.io/) but all features get the same style
the code

```
select.getFeatures().on(['add'], function (e) {
        var feature = e.element;       
  let styleNew =

      new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: color,
          width: 7,
        }),
      });
       
  let x=  feature.setStyle(styleNew);
  const newStyle = feature.getProperties();
    feature.setProperties({ name: name });
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a 'style' function on your vector layer definition. It will be called for each feature before rendering and should return the corresponding style.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        if (feature.get("NAME") == "Green") {
            return greenStyle;
        }
        else if (feature.get("NAME") == "Red") {
            return redStyle;
        }
        else {
            return otherStyle;
        }
    }
});
```

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_BaseVector-BaseVectorLayer.html#setStyle

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include the text in the feature's style, as a minimum the text, but unless you are happy to use the default font you will probably also want to the specify the font and the stroke and fill styles to use for the text.

```
  let styleNew =
      new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: color,
          width: 7,
        }),
        text: new Text({
          text: name,
        }),
      });
```

Comment: In the first thanks for you for this idea
second but I still have the same issue because all features will get same style and name
any idea please

Comment: `name` should be set to the name for that feature - `feature.get('name')` or whatever property from the data you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try this idea

Comment: I tried this idea but all features changed to same color and same name I couldn't change it individually

Comment: Do you mean when you select one feature all your other features also change style?

Comment: yes that what  I mean exactly

Comment: i found a solution  to change only selected feature by set new style but something strange happened when unselected its get vectorlayer style how can add new style to this feature only

Comment: In OpenLayers 6 the Select interaction sets a selected style when a feature is selected and resets the original style when deselected, so any changes you make will be lost.  Instead of using the Select interaction you can also select using pointer events (pointermove, click, etc.) on the map as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html which will give you better control of setting styles.